# Access web apps on host machine from Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, dns

I have a development environment where some services run in a local Kubernetes cluster, while others run in local nginx & IIS (Windows) outside of the cluster. Most of these services are HTTP APIs, and I sometimes need them to communicate to each other. I have found a way to for non-Kubernetes services to access services inside the cluster (by using IIS as a proxy), but not the other way around.

Basically, from within my container I need to be able to do `curl https://app-running-in-iis.local`. The address `app-running-in-iis.local` should resolve to the IP of the host running the Kubernetes cluster.

What would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a DNS resolving issue or routing issue?

Answer (score -1):

In *Kubernetes best practices*: [mapping external services](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services)

You can find two examples how to map external resources into your cluster using services and endpoints:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: nginx
Spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 31500
   targetPort: 27017

kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: nginx
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 10.240.0.4
   ports:
     - port: 27017
```

Additional resources:

- [Services without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)
- [Type ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)

Hope this help.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not helpful, because all these approaches assume that you know the IP address of the resource you want to access. I need to access the Kubernetes host machine, its IP address is unknown to me, and it can change after a restart.

Comment: So in this case do you have dns record for this host ?

Comment: The only host name that points to the host machine is `host.docker.internal`, but I cannot use it to access the websites because this machine runs several websites, each with their own host name.

Comment: From kubernetes container you are trying to reach external service? As mentioned in the answer you can also use `Type ExternalName` it will give you local service while the cluster DNS service return a CNAME record with the proper value. If this is not your case please elaborate more deeply. Anyway in order to connect from inside the cluster to the external service it should be accessible.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to clarify my question even more, but I'll try. I have a Windows machine running several websites `site1.local`, `site2.local`, etc. This is a development machine, so there're no public DNS records for these websites, they are only available on that single machine, and DNS records are configured via local `hosts` file. That same machine is running a k8s cluster, and I need all the pods to be able to resolve  `site1.local`, `site2.local` to the IP of the host machine (which is unknown to me and may constantly change), and access these 2 websites.

Comment: For clustering task on the windows host machine are you using Docker Desktop for Windows?

Comment: Yep,  Docker Desktop for Windows

Comment: It looks like solution from Docker:
[I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/)
`The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows.`

Comment: Still not helpful... If I curl to `host.docker.internal` from a pod, I will reach the default website of the host machine. But as I mentioned earlier, the host is running several websites, and I need to be able to reach all of them using their own host names `site1.local`, `site2.local`, etc